# Can an infrared laser be made visible with another type of laser?

Tags: laser

I was wondering, if you had an infrared(or ultraviolet) laser, is there any way that you could make it visible by intersecting it with another type of laser? For example, uv with uv, infrared with infrared, uv with infrared or even two low colored lights. Basically any way you can make something from invisible to visible by using another laser. And if none of those listed things would work, is there any other way you could think of to make some sort of visible point?

Comment: Second harmonic generation from 1064 nm Nd:YAG makes that nice green laser pointer light...

Comment: Or, to go from UV to visible, use a fluorescent material.

Comment: Piece of paper would work for UV, because of added optical brighteners. As for infrared there is nothing as ready available, but there are multiple materials that will emit visible upon IR excitation. Lookup detector cards (sometimes called laser viewing cards).

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering, if you had an infrared(or ultraviolet) laser, is there any way that you could make it visible by intersecting it with another type of laser?

Light beams go through each other, they do not interact, so you would not "see" anything in the projected overlap region. But two laser  beams in superposition can form an interference pattern , to see it you would need a method of recording it, a photon  detector as [discussed here.](http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/LaserInterference/LaserInterference.html)

> Basically any way you can make something from invisible to visible by using another laser.

Basically it needs a screen in order to see the interference between the two laser frequencies, and the screen should be such as to record  at least one of the frequencies under observation.

> And if none of those listed things would work, is there any other way you could think of to make some sort of visible point?

In the comments you are offered solutions for ultraviolet and infrared, that will show in optical frequencies that a laser has impinged on them. [This is offered](https://www.rp-photonics.com/laser_viewing_cards.html) for infrared.

Comment: The last link is the real answer. The problem of figuring out where the beam is for an IR or UV laser is not new -- it is an essential part of the process of working with and aligning those lasers, which are extremely common in lab and technological context (including in particular the telecomms wavelengths at ~1.5 microns). Laser viewing cards are core part of the experimental toolkit when working with those wavelengths.